# Mongo Aggregation: Using new Date() as in input to form a AggregationExpression

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

does anybody know how to achieve this statement with spring mongo projection:

```
timed: {
   $divide: [{ $subtract: [ new Date(), "$created" ] }, 7200000]
}
```

Something like this doesn't work for me:

```
ArithmeticOperators.Subtract updated = valueOf("new Date()").subtract("created");
```

because valueOf expects a field reference or an AggregationExpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below stage. `new Date()` in shell query is javascript date function. You have to use the `BasicDBObject` to wrap that expression inside the AggregationExpression.

```
 ArithmeticOperators.Divide updated = ArithmeticOperators.Divide.valueOf(aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("$subtract", Arrays.asList(new Date(), "$created"))).divideBy(7200000);
 AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project().and(updated).as("timed");
 Aggregation agg = newAggregation(project);
```

I was not able to find a way to pass something like two date arguments

```
valueOf("created").subtract(new Date())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This doesn't work as valueOf expects a Number value.. ord AggregationEspression or a fieldReference (given field in document)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem as you . I fix it by the following code:

```
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String dateNow = DateFormatUtil.getDateNow();
    DateOperators.DateFromString date = DateOperators.dateFromString(dateNow);
    date.withFormat(pattern);
    ArithmeticOperators.Subtract subtract = ArithmeticOperators.Subtract.valueOf("deadline").subtract(date);
    ArithmeticOperators.Divide divide = ArithmeticOperators.Divide.valueOf(subtract).divideBy(3600000);
```

subtract() method may need a param like  **AggregationExpression** , and the **DateOperators.dateFromString** is the implement.
I hope this can be helpful. 0-0